# VIM: Getting register into command with macro; replace all occurences with register

Tags: vim

I want to make a macro such that the current term searched is replaced by the last insert.

My incorrect approach:

```
map <C-r> :%s//"p./<CR>
```

How can I get the register . into my substitute command?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can insert any register's contents in command-line mode via `:help c_CTRL-R`:

```
nnoremap <C-r> :%s//<C-r>./<CR>
```

#### Notes

- [You should use `:noremap`](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/05.html); it makes the mapping immune to remapping and recursion.
- Limit the mapping to as few modes as possible. I don't think you need to trigger this from visual mode or operator-pending mode, so `:nnoremap` fits best.
- Your mapping only replaces the *first* occurrence in each line unless you add the `/g` flag. `/e` flag may also make sense to suppress the error when there are no matches.
- `<C-R>` in normal mode is redo; remapping such a crucial command is not recommended, losing it completely is even worse.

Comment: Thanks, didn't realize it is redo, you probably saved me a couple of minutes of head-scratching :) . Ended up swapping it to <C-c> for "change".

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for `@.` or `getreg('.')`. But as they are expressions, you'd need `:exe`. This would be convoluted.

Another way consists in using `:h c_CTRL-R`:

```
nnoremap <c-r> :%s//<c-r>./<cr>
```

PS: I usually avoid to trigger mappings on keysequences that already do things. In particular when they do important and critical stuff. Here `CTRL-R` is redo. I'm quite certain you don't want to loose that.